# Unknown error causes in function @@ "expected expression"

Tags: c, expression

Im in a bit of a trouble calling out and making functions and their prototypes. Can anyone validate and give tips given function with prototype?

prototype: `int sumpa(int sum, int arv[])`

function call-out: `sumpa(sum, arv);`

function:

```
int sumpa(int sum, int arv[])
{
int i;
i=0;

for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)   // sum array (User input, MAX=3)
sum=sum+arv[];
printf("\n sum = %d", sum);

return (0);
}
```

But this line   gives me unexpected expression error?!

```
    sum=sum+arv[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` square brackets form the *subscript operator*, which expects **an argument** to index the object it is called on.

Instead, use `arv[i]` to get the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of `arv`.

Comment: Thanks, totally didnt think of it!!!

Comment: @Coralina Please accept an answer to mark this problem as solved.